# iOS 7 Ranging beacons: Sometimes ranging is Unavailable, and the only solution is reboot the device

Tags: iphone, ios7

I'm working with Beacons on iOS 7.x, usually works fine but sometimes when I call `startRanging...`, device launch me the error kCLRangingUnavailable, after check with wifi disabled, restart bluetooth, and start and stop airplain mode, the only solution of this problem was reboot the phone.

This is my Sourcecode:
    @interface RBTMainViewController () 
    @property (nonatomic, retain)    CLLocationManager* locationManager;
    @end

```
@implementation RBTMainViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        _locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _locationManager.delegate=self;

        NSUUID *estimoteUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"00001111-2222-3333-4444-555566667777"];
        CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:estimoteUUID
                                                                    identifier:@"Proves Range"];

        if ([CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
        {
            [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
            [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"This device does not support monitoring beacon regions");
        }


    }
    return self;
}
...
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"monitoringDidFailForRange: %@ withError: %@", region, error);

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager rangingBeaconsDidFailForRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"rangingBeaconsDidFailForRange: %@ withError: %@", region, error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"monitoringStart: %@", region);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"RangingBeacons: %@ in (%@)", beacons, region);

}
@end
```

And this is the ouput in the iPhone when the errors happens:

```
2014-04-14 13:20:18.628 RangingBeaconsTest[9042:60b] monitoringStart: CLBeaconRegion (identifier:'Proves Range', uuid:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x15554170> 00001111-2222-3333-4444-555566667777, major:(null), minor:(null))
2014-04-14 13:20:23.752 RangingBeaconsTest[9042:60b] rangingBeaconsDidFailForRange: CLBeaconRegion (identifier:'Proves Range', uuid:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x15565390> 00001111-2222-3333-4444-555566667777, major:(null), minor:(null)) withError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=16 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 16.)"
```

This code error, is the unavailable ranging. Somebody can help me with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Bug in iOS 7, filed my bug report: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059255/ios-7-ranging-beacons-sometimes-ranging-is-unavailable-and-the-only-solution-i